# How to derive years of service for employees that have termed and returned several times

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm working with Oracle and have sample data to show you regarding my question (sample data is below).

I'm trying to figure out how to derive years of service for employees that have terminated and returned several times (up to 6 times).  The business rules are that if someone leaves and returns before 365 days, then we bridge their service -- otherwise we don't.  Bridging is determined by the "Yes" and "No" values in the BRIDGE fields.

My sample data below: The HIRE, TERM and BRIDGE fields go up to 3 levels but it can at times go all the way up to 6 levels deep for some employees.

```
╔════════╦════════════╦════════════╦══════════╦════════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦═══════════╗
║ EMPLID ║   HIRE_1   ║   TERM_1   ║ BRIDGE_1 ║   HIRE_2   ║  TERM_2   ║ BRIDGE_2 ║  HIRE_3   ║
╠════════╬════════════╬════════════╬══════════╬════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬═══════════╣
║   1001 ║ 9/22/2011  ║ 12/9/2011  ║ Yes      ║ 7/1/2012   ║ 7/2/2013  ║ Yes      ║ 5/3/2014  ║
║   1002 ║ 3/29/1999  ║ 6/30/1999  ║ Yes      ║ 1/24/2000  ║ 3/29/2004 ║ No       ║ 11/5/2007 ║
║   1003 ║ 8/16/2009  ║ 12/31/2009 ║ Yes      ║ 1/1/2010   ║ 5/15/2012 ║ Yes      ║ 9/5/2012  ║
║   1004 ║ 7/23/2007  ║ 8/21/2009  ║ Yes      ║ 3/1/2010   ║ 2/9/2011  ║ Yes      ║ 4/25/2011 ║
║   1005 ║ 5/11/2010  ║ 8/31/2010  ║ Yes      ║ 7/1/2011   ║ 5/5/2012  ║ Yes      ║ 9/6/2012  ║
║   1006 ║ 1/17/2009  ║ 5/8/2009   ║ Yes      ║ 12/8/2009  ║ 5/4/2010  ║ Yes      ║ 1/18/2011 ║
║   1007 ║ 9/20/2004  ║ 5/4/2007   ║ No       ║ 11/15/2010 ║ 1/21/2011 ║ Yes      ║ 2/16/2011 ║
║   1008 ║ 6/22/2009  ║ 8/29/2009  ║ No       ║ 5/9/2011   ║ 4/13/2012 ║ Yes      ║ 5/21/2012 ║
║   1009 ║ 10/13/2008 ║ 5/9/2009   ║ Yes      ║ 8/24/2009  ║ 5/25/2010 ║ Yes      ║ 8/10/2010 ║
║   1010 ║ 8/13/2008  ║ 5/7/2010   ║ Yes      ║ 1/4/2011   ║ 5/31/2011 ║ Yes      ║ 8/15/2011 ║
║   5011 ║ 7/3/1985   ║ 10/24/2000 ║ No       ║ 7/19/2010  ║           ║ No       ║           ║
╚════════╩════════════╩════════════╩══════════╩════════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩═══════════╝
```

For the last entry, 5011, the employee was rehired on 7/19/2010 and hasn't left. So the calculation should be a little less than 5 years (4.xx). Because the prior termination date between the next hire date was more than 365 days, `bridge_1` is "No". So this resets years recognized for service. Otherwise if the employee was rehired less than 365 days from the prior term, then the `bridge_1` would be yes.

I'm looking for the most recent period of bridged employment, so if there are two periods separated by a gap of more than a year (as for employee 5011) then I only want the most recent, not the total of all the separate contiguous (bridged) periods.

Comment: Is absence time counted when you "bridge"? Say you get hired on 1/1/2012, leave on 3/1/2012, then come back 4/1/2012, and leave again on 6/1/2012. Do you get four months (jan,feb,apr,may) or five month (jan,feb,mar,apr,may)?

Comment: Is normalising your data structure an option? I'd strongly recommend it.

Comment: Hi amcdermott.  Thanks for your response.  In your example, you would get five months for (jan,feb,mar,apr,may).  I don't have an option of revising how I consume the data either (can't normalize it). Thanks!

Comment: So your table has `hire_1`, `hire_2`, up to `hire_6`? Or is this a view or subquery that's pivoting underlying (normalised) data?

Comment: Yes, all the way up to hire_6.  It's a view that's pivoting the normalized data from Peoplesoft (in Oracle).   I don't have access to the underlying normalized data unfortunately. Thanks for your help Alex.

Comment: keep it simple.  add a new table where you store a single prior service total row per employee.  Only calculate current service time+this prior service total.  Only include prior service that should be included in this table.  populate this table when activating an employee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @PonderStibbons pointed out, this can be done quite simply by adding together the span of each hired period, and also adding the span of the between-hiring periods if the bridge value is 'Yes'. Open-ended hirings and different numbers of hirings can be handled by treating all null dates as the same, presumably as sysdate if you want the current hiring period to be counted up to today.

You can either calculate as days and divide by a nominal value for the number of days in the year ([again as Ponder showed!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/af9fe/3)), or use month subtraction and divide by 12:

```
select emplid,
  round((months_between(nvl(term_1, sysdate), hire_1)
    + case when bridge_1 = 'Yes' then months_between(hire_2, term_1) else 0 end
    + months_between(nvl(term_2, sysdate), nvl(hire_2, sysdate))
    + case when bridge_2 = 'Yes' then months_between(hire_3, term_2) else 0 end
    + months_between(sysdate, nvl(hire_3, sysdate))) / 12, 2) as total_years
from t42
order by emplid;

    EMPLID TOTAL_YEARS
---------- -----------
      1001        3.74
      1002       12.62
      1003        5.84
      1004        7.90
      1005        5.10
      1006        6.42
      1007        7.21
      1008        4.29
      1009        6.68
      1010        6.85
      1011        3.31
      1012        2.21
      5011       20.22
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0590/1)

For all six potential hiring periods, repeat the pattern; only the first and last clauses in the addition will be different, as hire_1 is always present, and term_6 won't exist.

---

If you only want the most recent contiguous/bridged period, not the total of all contiguous/bridged periods, you need to be more selective about which periods are included - starting from the most recent and working backwards, taking all later bridges into account:

```
select emplid,
  round((
    -- 3rd period
    months_between(sysdate, nvl(hire_3, sysdate))
      -- gap between 3rd and 2nd
      + case when (hire_3 is not null and bridge_2 = 'Yes') then
          months_between(hire_3, term_2) else 0 end
      -- 2nd period
      + case when (hire_3 is null or bridge_2 = 'Yes') then
          months_between(nvl(term_2, sysdate), nvl(hire_2, sysdate)) else 0 end
      -- gap between 2nd and 1st
      + case when (hire_3 is not null and bridge_2 = 'Yes')
            and (hire_1 is not null and bridge_1 = 'Yes') then
          months_between(hire_2, term_1) else 0 end
      -- 1st period
      + case when (hire_3 is null or bridge_2 = 'Yes')
            and (hire_2 is null or bridge_1 = 'Yes') then
          months_between(nvl(term_1, sysdate), nvl(hire_1, sysdate)) else 0 end
    ) / 12, 2) as total_years
from t42
order by emplid;

    EMPLID TOTAL_YEARS
---------- -----------
      1001        3.74
      1002        7.62
      1003        5.84
      1004        7.90
      1005        5.10
      1006        6.42
      1007        4.59
      1008        4.11
      1009        6.68
      1010        6.85
      1011        3.31
      1012        1.88
      5011        4.91
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0590/2), including a breakdown for each period/gap if it is should be included.

Comment: To clarify: The employee was rehired on 7/19/2010 and hasn't left. So the calculation should be a little less than 5 years (4.xx). Because the prior termination date between the next hire date was more than 365 days, bridge_1 is "No". So this resets years recognized for service. Otherwise if the employee was rehired less than 365 days from the prior term, then the bridge_1 would be yes. Hopefully this makes sense. I mentioned this in my original question, "The business rules are that if someone leaves and returns before 365 days, then we bridge their service -- otherwise we don't.

Comment: `╔════════╦══════════╦════════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦════════╗
║ EMPLID ║  HIRE_1  ║   TERM_1   ║ BRIDGE_1 ║  HIRE_2   ║ TERM_2 ║
╠════════╬══════════╬════════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬════════╣
║   5011 ║ 7/3/1985 ║ 10/24/2000 ║ No       ║ 7/19/2010 ║        ║
╚════════╩══════════╩════════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩════════╝`

Comment: @BillRoberts - I've added the 5011 data to the table in the question, and copied most of your explanation too (and added my own summation, which you're free to edit or remove of course). The comments on here are duplicating that now so you can remove them.

Answer (score 1):

If you were working with the underlying data rather than the pivoted view you could use analytics and a gaps-and-isands approach. It's overkill here as @PonderStibbons pointed out<sup>1</sup> but you *could* unpivot what you have back to something close to its original form:

```
with cte1 as (
  select t.emplid, t.num, t.hire, nvl(t.tmp_term, sysdate) as term,
    bridge as prev_bridge,
    nvl(lead(bridge) over (partition by emplid order by num), 'No') as next_bridge
  from (select t42.*, null as term_3, 'No' as bridge_0 from t42)
  unpivot ((hire, tmp_term, bridge) for num in (
    (hire_1, term_1, bridge_0) as 1,
    (hire_2, term_2, bridge_1) as 2,
    (hire_3, term_3, bridge_2) as 3)) t
)
select * from cte1;

    EMPLID        NUM HIRE       TERM       PRE NEX
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --- ---
      1001          1 2011-09-22 2011-12-09 No  Yes
      1001          2 2012-07-01 2013-07-02 Yes Yes
      1001          3 2014-05-03 2015-06-16 Yes No 
      1002          1 1999-03-29 1999-06-30 No  Yes
      1002          2 2000-01-24 2004-03-29 Yes No 
      1002          3 2007-11-05 2015-06-16 No  No 
...
```

This adds dummy `term_3` and `bridge_0` columns to the table; then unpivots it so you get one row for each set of entires; then it defaults the last open-ended hire to end at today's date, on the assumption you want their total hire time up to today. Because the default behaviour of unpivot is to exclude nulls, this will not create rows for unused 'levels', just up to the last hire date.

I've only used the three sets, but you can easily extend this to all six by changing the dummy column names to `term_6` etc. and adding more `in` clauses.

From that you can see the contiguous periods, and can ignore any row where which is bridging both sides - where `prev_bridge` and `next_bridge` are both Yes. (Normally you'd use both lead and lag to work this out from the dates, but might as well use the bridge flags we already have).

```
with cte1 as (
  ...
),
cte2 as (
  select emplid, num,
    case when prev_bridge = 'No' then hire end as hire,
    case when next_bridge = 'No' then term end as term
  from cte1
  where prev_bridge = 'No' or next_bridge = 'No'
)
select * from cte2
order by emplid, num;

    EMPLID        NUM HIRE       TERM     
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      1001          1 2011-09-22           
      1001          3            2015-06-16
      1002          1 1999-03-29           
      1002          2            2004-03-29
      1002          3 2007-11-05 2015-06-16
...
```

From that you can get the total period covered by each contiguous group, by using lead and lag to compress the periods split across rows (with null hire or term), and using distinct since that will generate duplicates:

```
with cte1 as (
  ...
),
cte2 as (
  ...
),
cte3 as (
  select distinct emplid,
    case when hire is null then lag(num)
      over (partition by emplid order by num) else num end as num,
    months_between(case when term is null then lead(term)
        over (partition by emplid order by num) else term end,
      case when hire is null then lag(hire) 
        over (partition by emplid order by num) else hire end) as period_months
  from cte2
)
select emplid, period_months
from cte3
order by emplid, num;

    EMPLID PERIOD_MONTHS
---------- -------------
      1001         44.83
      1002         60.00
      1002         91.38
...
```

And finally sum those distinct periods:

```
with cte1 as (
  select t.emplid, t.num, t.hire,
    nvl(t.tmp_term, sysdate) as term, bridge as prev_bridge,
    nvl(lead(bridge) over (partition by emplid order by num), 'No') as next_bridge
  from (select t42.*, null as term_3, 'No' as bridge_0 from t42)
  unpivot ((hire, tmp_term, bridge) for num in (
    (hire_1, term_1, bridge_0) as 1,
    (hire_2, term_2, bridge_1) as 2,
    (hire_3, term_3, bridge_2) as 3)) t
),
cte2 as (
  select emplid, num,
    case when prev_bridge = 'No' then hire end as hire,
    case when next_bridge = 'No' then term end as term
  from cte1
  where prev_bridge = 'No' or next_bridge = 'No'
),
cte3 as (
  select distinct emplid,
    case when hire is null then lag(num)
      over (partition by emplid order by num) else num end as num,
    months_between(case when term is null then lead(term)
        over (partition by emplid order by num) else term end,
      case when hire is null then lag(hire) 
        over (partition by emplid order by num) else hire end) as period_months
  from cte2
)
select emplid, sum(period_months) as total_months,
  round(sum(period_months)/12, 2) as total_years
from cte3
group by emplid
order by emplid;

    EMPLID TOTAL_MONTHS TOTAL_YEARS
---------- ------------ -----------
      1001        44.83        3.74
      1002       151.38       12.62
      1003        70.00        5.83
...
```

You said you wanted the answer in years, so you can divide by 12, and optionally truncate (or round, or floor, or ceil); you may want to do that before you sum or after you sum, which may give different results sometimes, but I've done if after here just as a demo.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/af9fe/1) with full results, including for a row that only has the first hire date, and a row with two gaps.

---

If you're only interested in the most recent contiguous/bridged period, this can be simplified to:

```
with cte1 as (
  select t.emplid, t.num,
    case when t.bridge = 'No' then t.hire else null end as hire,
    case when t.hire is not null and t.term is null
      then sysdate else t.term end as term
  from (select emplid, 'No' as bridge_0, hire_1, term_1,
    nvl2(hire_2, bridge_1, null) as bridge_1, hire_2, term_2,
    nvl2(hire_3, bridge_2, null) as bridge_2, hire_3, null as term_3
    from t42
  )
  unpivot ((hire, term, bridge) for num in (
    (hire_1, term_1, bridge_0) as 1,
    (hire_2, term_2, bridge_1) as 2,
    (hire_3, term_3, bridge_2) as 3)) t
)
select emplid,
  round(months_between(max(term), max(hire)) / 12, 2) as total_years
from cte1
group by emplid
order by emplid;

    EMPLID TOTAL_YEARS
---------- -----------
      1001        3.74
      1002        7.62
      1003        5.84
      1004        7.90
      1005        5.10
      1006        6.42
      1007        4.59
      1008        4.11
      1009        6.68
      1010        6.85
      1011        3.31
      1012        1.88
      5011        4.91
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0590/3).

---

<sub>1 - don't look at the edit history...</sub>

Comment: ALEX DID IT!  Wow.  It's working as expected.  Thanks.  You're a genius!

Comment: Great answer, (as always), but I don't understand one thing. 
Did you assume that there may be two rows for one employee? If not - answer could be much simplier: `select id, term_1-hire_1+decode(bridge_1, 'yes', hire_2-term_1, 0) +` ... etc. and divide result by [365.2425](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year), and of course [fun with nvl](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/af9fe/3). 
In OP's examples there is no repeating value for one id. Sorry if I missed something.

Comment: @PonderStibbons - I assumed one row per employee. I started considering that kind of approach but thought it was messy, esp. with an unknown number of values to consider (up to 6 anyway), and for each decode to consider previous bridge values to figure out *which* previous hire to use. I probably should have reconsidered when this got a bit complicated too. And I was overthinking the nvl fun a bit.

Comment: @PonderStibbons - ohhh, no, I see what you're doing; deciding whether to count the gaps... I was trying to adjust the hire/term based on the bridge value. Yes, that is much simpler, isn't it? I still might have used months_between for each part rather than date arithmetic and a fixed number of days to represent a year, but minor detail. Worth writing that approach up. (I guess I went the wrong route from early hopes of seeing the underlying data. What a waste!)

Comment: Yes, working on pivoted results is... weird. Columns `bridge_` seems redundant, but if they were I used them ;-) And in general - we had not desired output, examples with nulls, any OP's try... 
At first I did not answer this question because it seemed to me like another race ;-) Thanks.

Comment: @PonderStibbons - I've added that approach as a separate answer for now; not sure if you planned to answer it, but I'll happily remove mine if you do. Or CW it. (I might remove this one too...)

Comment: I did not plan. I think this question is very specific and answers will not be useful for more people, 
so it is better not to do unnecessary clutter and better delete this new, possibly add a link to my fiddle, if you want. 
Your answer is good, it adds interesting information about UNPIVOT etc. Again, thank you Alex.